# Run a batch file when I lock/unlock my computer

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, lock

Is there a way I can run a batch file upon locking my computer, and then run another batch file when I unlock it? (Windows 8.1)

Thank you!

Comment: Yes use a schedule task

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am sorry I can't give you english screenshots.
Just create a task in planned tasks.
At the "trigger" tab, you can select "At lock" and "At unlock".

Comment: Is this the view you're talking about? http://i.imgur.com/X6q5iNH.png Where are the triggers?

Comment: If I go to 'create basic task' I eventually get to this screen http://i.imgur.com/gJAvO43.png and there are so many options!! I can't find lock and unlock.

Comment: Not Basic Task. "Create new task". -> Sorry, I don't have an english Windows here.

Answer (score 0):

As user294496 pointed out, one of the fastest ways to do this would be to set a "Scheduled Task" up to execute your batch files at lock/unlock.

Another option would be to [take a look here](http://win7suspendresume.codeplex.com/) and see if this little GUI tool that somebody wrote for something similar might be a better option for you if you don't want to do this using scheduled tasks. If you are interested in writing some C#, I'll bet it wouldn't be too difficult to write a utility similar to this.